# django error where even though i allowed an attribute in url it isn't working

Tags: python, django, attributes

```
path('', views.index, name='index')
```

above code works when url: ...8000/app

```
path('<str:name>', views.index, name='index')
```

but this doesn't work when url: ...8000/app/kenny
gives page not found error

does anyone why it is working with no attributes but not with attributes. Same for other paths also.

Comment: please check official doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: when you go ``127.0.0.1:8000/app`` it serve ``path('<str:name>', views.index, name='index')`` this pattern because it contain slug and when you try to access ``127.0.0.1:8000/app/kenny`` than it will show you 404 because you don't have any pattern that match given url.

Comment: if you want to access this ``127.0.0.1:8000/app/kenny`` url than either you add url pattern like this ``path('app/<str:name>', views.index, name='index')`` or like this ``path('<str:name>/<str:name>', views.index, name='index')``

Comment: it still doesn't work. if you were correct then even the first url won't work. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I got it you have to put "/" before the first attribute of path()